# Will Eida's ability work on Naruto and Sasuke?

Tags: naruto, boruto

As of Chapter 57 of the Boruto manga, the newly revealed cyborg named Eida possesses the ability to

> Make people fall in love with her.

However, this ability does not work on blood relatives, and Otsutsuki. But, Naruto and Sasuke are the reincarnations of Indra and Asura, and each are respectively from a clan descended from the Otsutsuki.

Considering this, would Eida's ability work on Naruto and Sasuke? Or do you have to be a direct Otsutsuki for this not to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but I believe not, as Naruto and Sasuke are the reincarnations, their blood is still very much Uzumaki and Uchiha, but it is also said that Uzumaki and Uchiha are descendants from the Otsutsuki's, so it won't be known until she tries it on Naruto and Sasuke.